# My GUI wont open, i still get a stack overflow however

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ObtainData extends Thread {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    int i = 0;
    JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();
    public ObtainData(int port) throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        serverSocket.setSoTimeout(900000);
    }

    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Starting connection");
                Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
                BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(ImageIO
                        .createImageInputStream(server.getInputStream()));
                addImage(jpanel, img);
                jpanel.setVisible(true);
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException s) {
                System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
                break;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void addImage(JComponent parent, BufferedImage img) {
        JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
        jLabel.setBounds(parent.getBounds());
        parent.add(jLabel);
        parent.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        try {
            Thread t = new ObtainData(port);
            t.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Just like the title says, when I run this code I get a stack overflow, however, the GUI won't even appear. Anyone know why? I looked into it however nothing i can figure out is leading me to the right direction

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, it doesn't appear **because** you get the stackoverflow.

Comment: I don't see any GUI code in your posted code, other than a JPanel that is never added to or displayed in a top-level window. Why are you expecting to see a GUI?

Comment: How do I display a Jpanel in a top level window? @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: 1) you'd read the Swing tutorials and learn how to create a simple Swing GUI. 2) then create a JFrame and add your JPanel to the JFrame as the tutorials would show you. A JPanel by itself is less than worthless. Also as a side bit, you don't need to nor want to keep creating JLabels. Simply add a single JLabel to wherever you want to display your image and then set its Icon when you want to change images. You can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info)